# Autocomplete window appearing in wrong place for NSTokenField

Tags: cocoa, autocomplete, appkit, nstokenfield

I have a layer-backed NSTokenField that is in a NSSplitView. The split is initially collapsed, with the token field hidden. When I reveal the token field, it works properly, except that the autocomplete menu is in the wrong place: instead of being attached to the field, it appears at the bottom left of the window.

It seems like the menu is positioned before the view is in the window, or something like that.

Anyone else seen this, or have a possible workaround?

Comment: Well thats wierd. I have a token field in a view based table cell, and am seeing the same thing. I'm sure it didn't use to do that. I tried reverting to a version before I turned on autolayout but it's the same.

My tokenfield is in a view based tableview, so I can't try it on snow leopard.

Please report back if you find anything, I'll keep digging also.

Comment: I've submitted this issue to Apple via Radar (#10151857).

Comment: This seems to be a genuine bug in the OS. It only afflicts layer-backed NSTokenFields.